# Same launch file error even after changing ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin, roshydro, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just want to be able to use my custom launch files and am not having much success getting them to work.

Since I'm still new I didn't want to mess with the .bashrc file yet.

Edit: I added this to the .bashrc and it still didn't work

> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/mycomputer/Desktop/workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

I'll provide the steps I did and maybe someone can tell me where I went wrong. I've looked through all of the tutorials on the ROS wiki, googled, and looked on here and am still coming up short.

I created a copy of openni_launch and renamed test_openni_launch on my desktop.  I also created a barebones example_launch with example.launch inside a launch folder and a package.xml.  I went to a new terminal and typed:

> export | grep ROS

I then changed my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH from

> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/hydro/share"

to

> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/my_computer/Desktop:/opt/ros/hydro/share"

Yet I still receive the same message:

> [test_openni.launch] is neither a launch file in package [test_openni_launch] nor is [test_openni_launch] a launch file name

I've been looking at the structure of launch files and I don't think it's my problem, I think that the path is my problem.  I've been unable to resolve this, so I'm hoping someone can help.  If I completely change the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH like so:

> declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/my_computer/Desktop"

It returns this for roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch:

> Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1].

> Param xml is param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/

And does the same "invalid package" for my example.launch as previously shown.

Any ideas?

Edit2: I checked the answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/70435/confusion-with-ros_package_path/) and it looks like my method of adding a folder from the desktop should be valid.  What gives?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114941/same-launch-file-error-even-after-changing-ros_package_path/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-01-07**:
did you solve your problem?

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-07**:
Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer to what my issue was: http://answers.ros.org/question/115101/how-do-i-write-my-own-launch-files-in-hydro/

I'm guessing the test package provides all of the needed structure for ROS to recognize the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0